# systemd not working for dbus service

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, dbus, systemctl

I created one simple application which will just connect to system dbus. If I run the application manually, it is connecting to dbus. If I start using systemctl, the application is failling to connect to dbus.service file in /etc/systemd/system is attached below.

```
[Service]    
Type =dbus    
BusName=org.client
NotifyAccess=main    
ExecStart =/home/dbus/ProgramPract/LCM_test/client    
WatchdogSec = 10

[Install]    
WantedBy=basic.target
```

Comment: Have you started the service (and did it succeed? is it running?) or are you trying to create a DBus activatable service?

Comment: @jku Iam trying to create a dbus activable service. If I make it as a simple service also, iam getting same result.

Comment: You haven't described what the results are. Is there an error? Is the service binary running after manually starting the service? What _exactly_ fails?
If your issue is dbus-activation (and running manually works), then you need to show the dbus service file as well

Comment: @jku  my service binary is running successfully if I run manually. If I run as service, iam getting below error.   Jul 26 15:12:21 deepan-VirtualBox systemd[1]: helloworldService.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.


 >dbus service file  - i have no idea about this.

Comment: Please review the FAQ answer for [why things run differently under systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/339645/20239).